# Angular - menu - how to tab from the last menu item back to the first menu item

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

WCAG requires context or pulldown menu's to have a closed tab order. So, after tabbing to the last menu item of a menu, a subsequent tab should select the first menu item again.

I hoped the next solution would work. When tabbing in the second of three menu items, the third menu item is skipped and the first menu item gets the focus. Why is the third menu item skipped?

Question: how to tab each time from the 1st > 2nd > 3rd > 1st menu item?

**Attempt 1**: A tab to the third / last menu item will immediately go to the menu item 1.

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle
          (click)="open($event)">Actions</button>
  <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
    <button #firstbutton (click)="doAction( $event, 'Errors', journalEntry.id)"
            ngbDropdownItem>Errors</button>
    <button (click)="doAction( $event, 'Events', journalEntry.id)"
            ngbDropdownItem>Events</button>
    <button (click)="doAction( $event, 'Counts', journalEntry.id)"
            (keydown.tab)="gotoFirstMenuItem($event)" ngbDropdownItem>Counts</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The component:

```
@ViewChild("firstbutton") firstbutton: ElementRef;

gotoMenuItem(event, nextTabElement: number) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('tab on last menu item');
  this.firstbutton.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

**Attempt 2**: this will always skip 1 tab (or insert an extra tab);

The template:

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle
          (click)="open($event)" (keydown.enter)="open($event)">Actions</button>
  <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
    <button #firstbutton (click)="doAction( $event, 'Errors', journalEntry.id)"
            (keydown.enter)="doAction( $event, 'Errors', journalEntry.id)"
            (keydown.tab)="doNothing($event)"
            (keyup.tab)="gotoMenuItem($event, 2)"
            ngbDropdownItem>Errors</button>
    <button #secondbutton (click)="doAction( $event, 'Events', journalEntry.id)"
            (keydown.enter)="doAction( $event, 'Events', journalEntry.id)"
            (keydown.tab)="doNothing($event)"
            (keyup.tab)="gotoMenuItem($event, 3)"
            ngbDropdownItem>Events</button>
    <button #thirdbutton (click)="doAction( $event, 'Counts', journalEntry.id)"
            (keydown.enter)="doAction( $event, 'Events', journalEntry.id)"
            (keydown.tab)="doNothing($event)"
            (keyup.tab)="gotoMenuItem($event, 1)" ngbDropdownItem>Counts</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The component:

```
@ViewChild("firstbutton") firstbutton: ElementRef;
@ViewChild("secondbutton") secondbutton: ElementRef;
@ViewChild("thirdbutton") thirdbutton: ElementRef;

gotoMenuItem(event, nextTabElement: number) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('tab on last menu item');
  this.rowAction = 'Tab last menu item, going to first: ' + (++(this.tabCounterLastMenuItem));
  switch (nextTabElement) {
    case 1:
      this.firstbutton.nativeElement.focus();
      break;
    case 2:
      this.secondbutton.nativeElement.focus();
      break;
    case 3:
      this.thirdbutton.nativeElement.focus();
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to run this on Stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4t9syy?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I must admit, it behaved slightly differently then you described, maybe I didn't reproduce it properly i.e. in the first example it jumped to the first tab first, and then moved to the second, hence went 3->2, I suppose in your case it intercepted the event before it focused on the third item, it looks as if the

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

doesn't prevent default browser behavior, I tried changing it to

```
e.preventDefault();
```

it seems to work for the first example, at least in Stackblitz

Comment: Great! Thank you.